# Type DictionaryIterator does not conform to protocol 'Sequence' when returning DictionaryIterator from a container class

Tags: ios, swift, macos, dictionary, iterator

This code has the Swift compiler complaining about the second iteration using the returned `DictionaryIterator`:

```
import Foundation

class Container
{
    private var mArray: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    private var mDict: [Int:String] = [0: "value1", 1: "value2", 2: "value3"]

    func getArrayIterator() -> IndexingIterator<[String]>
    {
        return mArray.makeIterator()
    }

    func getDictIterator() -> DictionaryIterator<Int, String>
    {
        return mDict.makeIterator()
    }
}

let container = Container()

for value in container.getArrayIterator()
{
    print("Value: \(value)")
}

for (key, value) in container.getDictIterator() // Type 'DictionaryIterator<Int, String>' (aka 'Dictionary<Int, String>.Iterator') does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
{
    print("Key: \(key), value: \(value)")
}
```

<s>However, looking at the docs for the `Dictionary.Iterator` it seems it is actually conforming to protocol Sequence.</s>
**EDIT**:
It actually says that `Dictionary.Iterator` has a relationship "From Protocol" `Sequence`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/iterator

Why is this code not working?

Comment: Note that the documentation says it has a relationship from Sequence and not that it conforms to it. I’m honestly not quite sure what that means, having a relationship from, but it appears to be something different from conforming to a protocol

Comment: Good point! Interestingly, looking at the embedded documentation from Xcode I see the Dictionary.Iterator conforms to IteratorProtocol. Looking at that documentation it seems I should be able to use the for in construct on that.

Comment: Also interesting that the embedded Xcode documentation is not the same as the online documentation.

Comment: I think you’ve got a misapprehension about an iterator. The whole point is that while it underlies your ability to cycle thru something it is not itself cyclable except by repeated calls to `next`. For an iterator to be cyclable it itself would need an iterator and so on and the universe would explode. So use `while next` (that is pseudocode but you see what I mean) like everyone else and keep the universe safe!

Comment: Thank you, well explained. How come that the array iterator actually conforms to Sequence (and thus works)? Does it returns a copy of itself with `makeIterator()`?

Comment: Not exactly. :) An array's iterator is an IndexingIterator. A dictionary's iterator isn't. That's because an array is indexed (by number) and a dictionary is not. To put it another way, a dictionary is not ordered but an array is. But that's sort of an implementation detail; my separation of cyclability from the underlying iterator expresses the _general_ case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an iterator is not something you can say `for...in` to; it is the reason why you can say `for...in` to something else. Under the hood  `for...in` is actually a `while` loop that repeatedly calls `next` on the iterator. Now that you’ve looked behind the curtain, that is what you must use too.

So, for example, let's say we have a dictionary

```
let d = [1:"hey", 2:"ho"]
```

Then this:

```
for (i,s) in d {
    print(i, s)
}
```

is the equivalent of this:

```
var it = d.makeIterator()
while let (i,s) = it.next() {
    print(i,s)
}
```

And in fact under the hood, the former *is* the latter. There are situations where making a loop behave the way you want can be easier if you "unroll" `for...in` into the iterator form.

Now, in the particular case of an array, which is indexed by number, the iterator is an IndexingIterator, which itself has an iterator — which itself has an iterator and so on. It's turtles all the way down, ad nauseam:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let whoa = arr.makeIterator().makeIterator().makeIterator() // !!!!
for i in whoa {
    print(i)
}
```

You could carry on with that `whoa` definition as long as you like.

Comment: Are the next lines of code equal in terms of functionality? `var it = container.getDictIterator(); while let (key, value) = it.next()` and `for in (key, value) in container.getDictIterator()`

Comment: Sort of. I've added a code equivalence example to my answer.

Comment: Could you please merge you comment about the world exploding :-) with this answer? It really helpt in understanding what you meant. The point about an Iterator returning an Iterator (by makeIterator()) made it click.

Comment: I added the array example, I think that makes it clear why it's sort of special in this regard. The universe did not explode so far, but you never know.